# Get image coordinates on mouse click python Jupyter

Tags: python, image, image-processing, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am new in python and juypter. I am working on a task that is running on server which cannot use any graphic interface like LabelMe or RectLabel. I can only run a jupyter notebook on the remote server, and also connect to the remote jupyter notebook on my own computer.

What I am trying to do is to label images and get the coordinates of the labels. I have tried getting coordinates on mouse click using matplotlib but it doesn't seems to work. I can't click on the plots.